# how to set seleniumserver loglevel to info?

Tags: selenium, logging

I am trying to start selenium and selenium server in the same instance. And I use RemoteControlConfiguration.setLogOutFileName($myFileName) to appoint my log files, but I get the log in debug mode allways. The level I need is info, any suggestions?

protected static RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
protected static SeleniumServer server;

protected void startServer(String portList, String logPath) throws Exception{

```
String portStr[] = portList.split(";");
int portNum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < portStr.length; i ++){
    portNum = Integer.parseInt(portStr[i]);
    String logName = "selenium-server-" + portStr[i] + ".log";
    try{
        rcc.setPort(portNum);
        rcc.setBrowserSideLogEnabled(false);
        rcc.setDontTouchLogging(false);
        rcc.setDebugMode(false);
        rcc.setEnsureCleanSession(true);
        rcc.setReuseBrowserSessions(true);
        rcc.setLogOutFileName(logPath + logName);
        server = new SeleniumServer(false, rcc);
        server.start(); 
        server.getServer().start();
        break;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

}